# Which reflects more sunlight energy, aluminum or silver mirrors?

Tags: reflection

I am building a solar oven. 
I intend to use mirrors.
however I am uncertain how to determine which will reflect more sunlight, Aluminum or Silver mirrors. How to go about this?

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/116452

Answer (score 2):

At the infrared wavelengths where you will get most energy there is very little difference in reflectivity.

Aluminium mirrors are generally cheaper and will last longer. Silver mirrors quickly tarnish unless they are protective over-coated.

Answer (score 0):

The use of silver as the reflective layer is claimed to lead to higher efficiency levels, because it is the most reflective metal.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_mirror